# Need to add css style to an iframe using javascript from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append, parent

Here is what I have so far:

```
var head = $target.prop("iframe").toLowerCase().contents().find("head");
var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
          'MY CSS IS HERE' +
          '</style>';
jQuery(head).append(css);
```

Unfortunately, I have a couple issues:

1) I can't add jquery to the page via javascript (I tried but it's not working), so I need this converted to javascript.

2) I'm sure there is something wrong with the code. Please help me fix the errors.

---

NOTE:

I already tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page), but it does none of that is working especially because it's different than what I need (THERE IS NO ID OR CLASS NAME FOR THE IFRAME so everything on that question is irrelevant).

Comment: is the IFRAME page under the same domain or subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have iframe page under the same domain you schold try this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('head').append('<style type="text/css">' +'MY CSS IS HERE' + '</style>')
```